# How to run an Async SOQL query other than via Workbench

Tags: soql, workbench, async-soql

In [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), one can perform Async SOQL queries like so:

[image]

However, Workbench is strictly speaking not a Salesforce supported product. Is there another tool from which one can execute Async SOQL?

Answer (score 4):

Based on **[Running Async SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_running_queries.htm)**, it should be possible to obtain via callout, as it lists a `Request URI`:

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/async-queries/
```

The sample response body includes a `jobId` attribute, which you will ostensibly have to pass into the subsequently mentioned endpoint.

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/async-queries/<jobID>
```

These are tasks which should be straightforward to carry out via `Execute Anonymous` if you want the quick and dirty approach. Just don't forget to add your own org via `Remote Site Settings`. If you are running them often and the investment makes sense, it would be possible to build these calls into a controller and run them from a UI.

Comment: I don't have any orgs set up with anything to test against, unfortunately.